# NSTextField is first responder but I still must click inside the text box before typing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield, first-responder

My ultimate goal is to have an NSTextField selected by default allowing the user to start typing without clicking on the text field first.

I have a view controlled by a NSViewController.  The view contains several text fields.  The NSView and NSWindow are both custom subclasses.  The text field is not subclassed.  Just a standard NSTextField.

Inside awakeFromNIB for the view controller I have the code:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] makeFirstResponder:firstBox];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] firstResponder] class]));
```

The text field gets a focus ring around it, and the NSLog prints that the first responder is an NSTextField but I still have to click inside the text field before I can begin typing.

What could cause the field to be the first responder but not editable?  Is there a better method I should be calling makeFirstResponder from?

Comment: is the window in front and key when you set the textfield to be first responder?

Comment: Yes.  In applicationDidFinishLaunching I make the window key and order front.  The user will click a button on the first view which will switch the view controller and display the new view where the problem is occurring.

Comment: It seems to have to do with the fact that I'm making the field first responder in awakeFromNib.  If I create an IBAction that makes the NSTextField first responder and associate it to a button, when I click the button the text field becomes first responder and has the cursor in it and I can begin typing right away.

Comment: I've also tried using loadView but it has the same results that the field has a focus ring but I cannot type in it. `- (void) loadView {
    [super loadView];
    [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] makeFirstResponder:firstBox];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] firstResponder] class]));
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a [potentially useful hint on CocoaDev.com](http://cocoadev.com/MakingNSTextFieldActive), try doing this:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] 
    performSelector: @selector(makeFirstResponder:) 
         withObject: firstBox 
         afterDelay:0.0];
```